# Complete process of an article linking to a stock table

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to show me a concrete example with an article table linking to a stock table (for the size of a teeshirt as well as its quantity), all that bind to a table order (and in this table, **Persist the article taking into account the quantity and the size if the article is available.**). I try to store the quantity in session (Without creating quantity attributes in my entity) and if the user modifies the quantity, it is taken into account in the basket, but I can not persist **depending on the quantity and even less taking into account the Size of a tee shirt.**

For the final step, link the article table to the order and proceed to payment, I have no problems.

I've been blocking it for over a month. Could someone show me the process to retrieve a user's item based quantity, **size and persist as many times the item that there is quantity select according to its size.**

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand exactly what do you want to do. But, i think that you need stored the data in a session and after you need process this value into your entity.?

The session values has persist there:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Then the persist now is only logic. I suggest you that divide the question into small questions and then, you get a concret answer.